# Dietary management for diarrhea

Tags: diet, diarrhea

I have seen general practitioners / physicians recommending to diarrhea patients:

- no dietary restriction at all
- avoid "irritating food" such as spicy stuff
- avoid diary products

Why the different recommendations for the same medical condition? Also, these are advice to be followed with medication. What if no medication is given at all, e.g. when medical help is not available, what kind of dietary changes would be recommended to manage diarrhea, like certain food that could make the diarrhea worse, or perhaps make it better?

Comment: What's the condition in question? Different types of diarrhea require different treatment. Diarrhea in cholera is much different than diarrhea in IBS. A low-FODMAP diet can be a good start. It seems quite restrictive initially, but when you know the cause, you can adjust it.